# When I boot up my notebook PC from USB it shows me this: BOOTMGR is missing

Tags: installation, boot

When I boot up my notebook PC from USB it shows me this: BOOTMGR is missing
What could this mean? Please answer me.. I want to have Ubuntu! Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB disk is not bootable.  Please use proper method to prepare usb disk.

From Windows you can use following programs,

- [Lili](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)
- [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

From ubuntu, you can use

- Start up disk creator

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) is an utiliy that runs both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a guide to properly install ubuntu on a flashdrive here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/